# Retrieving song name by track id spotify without a oAuth key

Tags: api, spotify

I was trying to build a web app that uses spotify api to get the song/artist name by a track id(spotify), my intention was so everyone could use the web app, not only spotify users.

But I guess it's not possible to use the API without logging in the user ?

Can somebody confirm or maybe point me to a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you can register your application and use your secret to retrieve any non user-specific information.

[See this page.](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client_credentials_flow)

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that section after reading the whole documentation. Thanks a bunch mate !